# Regarding JQuery Script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wonder if JQuery can do something like http://ikt.co.id/
look at the flash right side... does it posible? and someone can send me a guide or script sample?

thanks guys!

Comment: jQuery can do AANNYYYTTHHIIINNNGGG.

Comment: Yes, u can do it.Jqyery rotate image/manipulation

Comment: Offtopic: my god that's an annoying effect, lol.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the [perspective](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_perspective.asp) CSS3 property for the start bit. But that is only currently supported by webkit browsers, such as Safari and Chrome.

From then on, using jQuery's [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) event to both stop the perspective and then to shift the padding of each element.